# How to trigger a tap event for element with on-tap='node_action'?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ractivejs

Usually I can use `fire` to activate handlers, but in this case I need to get full item data with `e.context` in event handler.

---

Update 08.05.15

**Detailed description**
Why I cannot just fire `node_action`?
I've a list of items and on tap I want to show item related info in the floating block near the item.
So I have `on-tap='node_action'` for each item and I have:

```
@on 'node_action', (e)->
  item = e.context — then I can use item.id to load data
  item_div = e.node — then I can use item_div.top_y() to show floating menu
                      on the same level on the page with the item div
```

Why do I need to trigger?
If I want to work on that floating menu I don't want to manually click on item every time after the page refresh, so I usually automate it with triggering events.

Yes, I can do fire here with prepared event like

```
e =
  context: ractive.get 'items.0'
  node: ractive.find '.items .line:first'
ractive.fire('node_action', e)
```

But items in the list can be sorted, filtered, and changed.

Ideally it would be nice to have something like this:

```
ractive.find('.items .line:first').tap()
```

or

```
ractive.find('.items .line:first').trigger 'tap'
```

or maybe

```
ractive.find('.items .line:first').fire 'node_action'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that it is actually possible with the [Simulant.js](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/Simulant) by Rich Harris.
It doesn't support the `tap` event, so for my needs I've added a small jQuery plugin

```
# Ractive trigger
# btn.r_trigger 'tap'
# btn.r_trigger 'click', {button:1, which:2}
$.fn.r_trigger = (event_name, opt)->
    el = @[0]
    switch event_name
        when 'tap'
            simulant.fire(el, 'mousedown', opt)
            simulant.fire(el, 'click', opt)
        else
            simulant.fire(el, event_name, opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

In reactive apps, it's usually a sign something's amiss when you want to get a DOM node to get to data. But without more detail hard to tell.

To answer what I think is your question, you can use the following to get the context, keypath and index from the node, similar to what you get from event context:

`var info = Ractive.getNodeInfo(node);`

Comment: >you want to get a DOM node to get to data —  
Actually I didn't want it.

getNodeInfo can be useful to prepare an event for fire, but it no as simple as just trigger event.

Comment: added Detailed description to the question